# Webauthn demo not wokring on safari

Tags: safari, webauthn

When testing various demos for webauthn, the `credentials.create()` function stopped working for safari (on mac), returning `NotAllowedError: Operation failed.` I tried these demos ([1](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/webauthn-reauth#0) , [2](https://webauthnworks.github.io/FIDO2WebAuthnSeries/) , [3](https://webauthn.me/)), and they all still work on chrome, but after being able to create two passkey credentials through safari, I can no longer use any webauthn demo (on my device) to create a credential (for any authenticator type). Nothing changed about my computer or my safari preferences. What could be going on here? Is there some setting to change in the `.create()` options that could prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Two potential causes spring to mind.

1. There are issues with ongoing concurrent WebAuthn requests, such as across multiple tabs. You may either have had a visible request going via a modal window, or have encountered a browser bug. In both cases, you'd see the issue clear up if you quit the browser (or force-quit on iOS-based platforms).
2. Because of the potential for abuse of modal UI, latest Safari institutes a policy where after the first request, subsequent requests may have to be triggered by user activation (e.g. a click). Older versions of Safari instituted more aggressive policies here, including not carrying that activation through a `fetch()`